# How can registered customer have two active quotes?

Tags: magento-enterprise, sales, quote, ee-1.12.0.2

I witness something strange, and I can't quite get a grip on it. I have only the data left to investigate, and here is what I have.

1. Registered customer created a quote A.
2. Before customer could checkout quote A, another but identical quote was created. Let's call this quote B.
3. Customer came back to his quote at some point and converted it into a sale. However, **he converted quote A**!
4. My data show quote A was converted into a sale and quote B was left as-is. Quote B was created about 5 hours before quote A was converted.

Other thing(s):

- There are no third-party extensions that create quotes.

Now, I don't understand how quote A was checked out and not B, **even** if somehow his session was interrupted and quote B was created for him.

Any ideas anybody?

Comment: Perhaps something is being cached that should not be?

Comment: We experienced the same in an EE installation. Which version do you use?

Comment: This is EE 1.12.0.2. @MatthiasZeis, how often are you experiencing this? This is the first time I found out about it just because it was reported by a customer who recovered his abandoned cart but was sent abandoned cart alert emails for quote B. This installation has been running at least a year.

Comment: Are you running multiple websites on the same instance? maybe one quote was for website X and the other for website Y. take a look at the `store_id` field in the `sales_flat_quote` table.

Comment: @laketuna: in that one store? Pretty often, I'd guess maybe 10% of the quotes are affected. One of the quotes is active, one inactive. We never experienced negative side effects. My guess is one of the extensions is the cause for this. @Marius: 1 website, 2 store groups, 5 store views. The quotes have the same `store_id`. Quotes are created in the same second.

Comment: @Marius, it's one store for entire instance (checked the store ID, too).

Comment: @MatthiasZeis, when your customer converts a quote to an order, which one does he convert to the order? The newer or older quote? The problem with this is particular case is that the OLDER quote was converted and the newer (identical to older) was left alone. This caused the abandoned cart alert to send out an email to the customer for the newer quote, even though he made the purchase he wanted, as far as he is concerned.

Comment: @MatthiasZeis are you, by any chance, using OneStepCheckout extension? because I had a lot of weird things happening with quotes.

Comment: laketuna: the newer one gets converted.
@JulienLachal: no, we are using GoMage_LightCheckout.
Looking at the current data, the duplicate rate has decreased to maybe about %1 (or even less). We have many extensions in the store so one of the updates in the last weeks/months may have improved the situation.